# Adobe Air HTML - How to add a drop shadow?

Tags: html, air, adobe, shadow

Does anyone know how to add a shadow to an Adobe Air app, made with HTML? I'm using the Window style "Custom chrome (transparent)" which removes the border, but it also removes the drop shadow.
If you're unsure what I mean, here's the drop shadow on a normal window:
[image]

And here's the Adobe Air app, which doesn't have a shadow:
[image]

Thanks for the help. :)

EDIT: Added images that actually show now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookbooks on the adobe site outline a couple of ways of doing this:

[Adding a drop shadow to a custom chrome window](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Adding_a_drop_shadow_to_a_custom_chrome_window-17644.html)

Comment: Ah, can I do that on a HTML AIR app? Where would I use that code?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I mis-read the title. For an html app, you could try setting a background image which has a drop shadow? This might not be the most efficient way. According to the [specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/ajax/articles/air_and_webkit.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_2) as of Air 3 most webkit css3 properties are supported - this should include the box-shadow property?

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, using that it drops a shadow. Still not as good looking as the Windows one, but meh. Thanks again. :)